# How to show mean MPG and HP by manufacturer only in mtcars python dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

im very new to using panda, and im trying to figure out how to do this problem. summarize: show the mean mpg and hp for each manufacturer. I have this code:

```
mtcars = pd.read_csv('mtcars.csv')

list(mtcars)
mtcars.describe()

mtcars.rename(columns={"Unnamed: 0": "Make n Model"}, inplace=True)

list(mtcars)
print(mtcars.groupby("Make n Model")[["mpg", "hp"]].mean())
```

Which makes a list, but I dont understand how I would sort by manufacturer only. Right now it just lists the MPG and HP for each car model. Any help is appreciated, I've been at this for hours

Comment: `list(mtcars)` doesn't do anything, why do you have that in the script? If you want to see the dataframe as a list, use `print(list(mtcars))` to show it.

Comment: Use `groupby("Manufacturer")` instead of `groupby("Make n Model")`

Comment: the problem is that I dont have a group for just the manufacturer.  This is what I've been struggling with

Comment: Is there a way you can extract the make from `Make n Model`? If it's always the first word, you can use a regular expression.

Comment: I think what I need to is separate the make and model from each other into different groups, but I dont understand how to do that

Comment: Make is always the first word followed by the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll consider that the "Make n Model" is the manufacturer column in your dataframe. So to groupby manufacturer and take the means and output a newer dataframe with manufacturers as index you would have to do

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(...)

df_grouped = df.groupby("Make n Model")[["mpg", "hp"]].mean()
```

If your goal is to have a column in the first dataframe with the mean mpg or hp by manufacturer you could do:

```
df["mean_mpg_manuf"]=df.groupby("Make n Model")["mpg"].transform("mean")
```

You could do the same for hp, the idea is that the .transform outputs a pandas series with the same size of the original dataframe with the values mapped to the manufacturer of each line

Comment: `Make n Model` is not the manufacturer, that's his problem. It's the model.

Comment: @Barmar in that case we would have to know what is the format of Make n Model to extract the manufacturer

Comment: Right. That's why I asked him where it is, and he said it's the first word.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to get the manufacturer from the make and model.

```
mtcars['Make'] = mtcars['Make n Model'].str.extract(r'^(\w+)')
```

Then you can use `.groupby('Make')`

Comment: im sorry, what does (r'^\w+') do at the end of that?

Comment: @Barmar I think you need a group in that regex: `.str.extract(r'^(\w+)')`